# Paired Opportunists chain reaction from seize the moment

Tags: pathfinder-1e

[Paired Oppertunist](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/paired-opportunists-combat-teamwork)

> Benefit: Whenever you are adjacent to an ally who also has this feat, you receive a +4 circumstance bonus on attacks of opportunity against creatures that you both threaten. Enemies that provoke attacks of opportunity from your ally also provoke attacks of opportunity from you so long as you threaten them (even if the situation or an ability would normally deny you the attack of opportunity). This does not allow you to take more than one attack of opportunity against a creature for a given action.

[Seize The Moment](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/seize-the-moment-combat-teamwork)

> Benefit: When an ally who also has this feat confirms a critical hit against an opponent that you also threaten, you can make an attack of opportunity against that opponent.

I am having a debate with somebody on the interaction of these 2 feats. From my reading RAW of paired Opportunist, a seize the moment crit will not trigger a paired opportunist free attack because the target did not provoke an attack of opportunity. Rather it was granted by your friend's feat. Also the flavor text of the feat indicates its related to the monster's "lax defense" which is not related to a feat chain reaction.

So step by step:

1. Character 1 gets a crit
2. Character 2 siezes the moment taking an attack of oppertunity
3. Character 1 gets to swing again because he has paired oppertunist and his friend took an attack of oppertunity?

Thoughts?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is no, the creature is not provoking an attack of opportunity--Seize the Moment is merely providing an AoO for something you normally wouldn't get.  Contrast this with the wording of Outflank (taken from pfsrd)

> Outflank (Combat, Teamwork) You look for every edge when flanking an
>   enemy.
>
> Prerequisite: Base attack bonus +4.
>
> Benefit: Whenever you and an ally who also has this feat are flanking
>   the same creature, your flanking bonus on attack rolls increases to
>   +4. In addition, whenever you score a critical hit against the flanked creature, ***it provokes*** an attack of opportunity from your ally.

The wording of these two feats is very different, and you can see via the italicized portion that if seize the moment were intended to work the way your friend describes it would also have to be worded this way.

Answer (score 6):

The question comes down to if the creature **provoked** an attack of opportunity. In this case, the monster did not provoke it, the feat provided it, so I would side with you.